# Django FieldError, one to many relationship

Tags: django-models

The behind my Django project is, that you can post projects, that includes the name, description, creationtime and deadline of the project, alongside images you can add.

In my Django project, I am using the Project and Image models to implement a one-to-many relationship. The Project model represents a project with fields such as project_name, project_description, created_at, and deadline. The Image model represents an image associated with a project and has a foreign key relationship with the Project model.

But when i do python manage.py makemigrations this Error appears:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (project_pictures) specified for Project

full traceback: Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\5aitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\5aitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 61, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, "url_patterns", [])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\5aitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Django2\Zimmer\zimmer\zimmer\urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    path('', include('projekte.urls')),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\5aitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Django2\Zimmer\zimmer\projekte\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "c:\Django2\Zimmer\zimmer\projekte\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from projekte.forms import ProjectForm
  File "c:\Django2\Zimmer\zimmer\projekte\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Django2\env\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 321, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (project_pictures) specified for Project
```

So i did a model, named "Project", that holds the project name, project description, when it was created and when the deadline is.
Then i did `return self.project_name`, so when i print or display a Project model, it should be represented by its project_name field value.

After that i did another model, called "Image", that has the field project, which has a relationship with the object "Project", then i did `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, so when i delete the Project, everything related with that object gets also deleted.
I did `related_name='project_images'`, to set the reverse relation name from the Project model back to the Image model. The idea behind it is, that it allows to access the set of Image objects associated with a Project instance. In my model, i can access the set of Image objects from a Project object using the project_images attribute.

This is my models file:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name


class Image(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_images')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

But for some reason it doesnt work, i googled it and asked chatgpt for help, but that didnt help much either. I dont understand the Error: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (project_pictures) specified for Project.
But i have some ideas, where it might come from. In my previous model there was a field that was called "project_pictures" and looked like that:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project_description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    project_pictures = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

I thought, the issue lied in the model Project, because it still had the column "project_pictures" and might tries to do something  with it, when i try to make the migration. Then i deleted that column, but then the exact same Error appeared. Im clueless where the error is, since now, i dont even have a field called "project_pictures". And if the error is related with a FieldError, it only can be the Model that does the issues, right?

My goal is, that i can create a project, where i can add more than one image.

I am more than greatful and thankful, if you can help me.

Comment: Can you please show how you *use* the models, and share the full traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out about where the problem was, it was in my forms.py file.
I forgot to delete, in the Meta class, 'project_pictures'.

How it looked like:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_description', 'deadline', 'project_pictures']
        widgets = {
            'deadline': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```

How it lookes like fixed:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['project_name', 'project_description', 'deadline', 'project_pictures']
        widgets = {
            'deadline': forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
        }
```